# Pasar Datos con ViewBag.Message

Tags: c#, asp.net

Quiero pasar un mensaje desde el controlador de la vista X a la visa Y

```
ViewBag.Message = "Mensaje";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Y");
```

al intentar esto no funciona, tampoco con el View(), como lo puedo pasar?

Answer (score 2):

Si haces un `RedirectToAction` lo que conseguirás es que se ejecute la acción del otro controlador, perdiendo los valores que hayas puesto en el `ViewBag`.

Si lo que quieres es renderizar la vista con la información generada en esta acción deberías devolverla con el método `View` indicando la ruta completa de la vista:

```
return View("~/Views/Y/Index.cshtml");
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, encontré el método para hacerlo, y sí tienes razón con el método RedirectToAction lo que consigo es ejecutar el otro controlador, entonces hay que pasarle el mensaje al controlador con el TempData:

TempData["Soporte"] = "Mensaje"
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Y");

Y en el controlador Y lo compruebo:

var t = TempData["Soporte"];

            if (t != null)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = t;
            }

Gracias